# how to download source version of a package

Tags: r

How can I download the source version of an R package so I can see the source code . Let's say I'd like to see the code of the quantreg pacakge.

Thank you.

Comment: Download the `Package source` from here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/quantreg/index.html. I did not downvote your question.

Comment: Whats with the downvotes?  after i download the tar.gz.... what do I do next....or can you provide a link with the steps

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about working with the R ecosystem, not about programming

Comment: I can't say what you have to do, but this R manual will help you with your question https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-admin.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For every package on CRAN, there is a part named **Package source** from which you can download the source code. See the picture, for example, in case of `quantreg`. Once you did download the source, navigate to the folder named **R** in which the r source files are placed. Needless to say, you must care about the **License** for every package in case you want to copy or distribute it (or whatsoever),

---

[image]